# SQL json extract where in array

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `users` table with `json` type `attributes` column:

**Example value:**

```
attributes: {"connection": "HTTP"},
attributes: {"connection": "API"}
```

When I tried get using `WHERE IN()` with one param all **works** correctly:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.connection') IN ("HTTP");`

But when I tried with multiple value it's **doesn't work** for me:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.connection') IN ("API", "HTTP");`

In this case return nothing. How I can get users which has one of defined connections inside `WHERE IN()` values?

Comment: seems to work here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08b428a0e13e5417541b0a36fdbe3e5d   have you tried selecting `JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.connection')` from the records you think should match and verified you are getting what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for answer! Really your code work on `MySQL 8` but my version is `MySQL 5.7` and therefore doesn't work. How can this be done in this version? @ysth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7 (possibly only later 5.7 versions; I saw some indications that some JSON_EXTRACT behavior changed in 5.7.10 or 5.7.11), it does not appear to cast the JSON value returned by JSON_EXTRACT to a string when used as the left operand to `IN`.  This will work in both 5.7 and 8.0:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.connection')) in ('HTTP','API');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ea3e311a775cf30e393b6ac07b7fde30